# skimulator - Python error message on Windows 10 - load_entry_point

Tags: python, error, climate, windows-10, anaconda

I am running `python` [code](https://git.oceandatalab.com/skim/skimulator) called [skimulator](https://forum.oceandatalab.com/thread-3.html) on `Windows 10` to [model](https://ftp.odl.bzh/odl/skim/) [Arctic ice drift and sea/wave velocities](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/earth-sciences/research/research-areas/polar-climate-modelling-and-change) for a satellite mission in 2025. Its installed using `Anaconda navigator` with a `python 3`, `Numpy`, `Scipy` and `NetCDF4` environment. Can anyone help with the first line error message?:

```
File "C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\Scripts\skimulator-script.py", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('skimulator==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'skimulator')()
```

Or even the whole error message?

`skimulator-script.py` code is shown below.

Error message in Anaconda prompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\Scripts>skimulator C:\Users\pclink\skimulator\example\params_2017v2_23W.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\Scripts\skimulator-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('skimulator==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'skimulator')()
  File "C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 484, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2707, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2325, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2331, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimulator-1.0-py3.7.egg\skimulator\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1140, in resource_filename
    self, resource_name
  File "C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1647, in get_resource_filename
    return self._extract_resource(manager, zip_path)
  File "C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1668, in _extract_resource
    timestamp, size = self._get_date_and_size(self.zipinfo[zip_path])
KeyError: 'skimulator\\share\\VERSION.txt'
```

skimulator-script.py   :

```
#!C:\Users\pclink\Anaconda3\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'skimulator==1.0','console_scripts','skimulator'
__requires__ = 'skimulator==1.0'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('skimulator==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'skimulator')()
    )
```

Comment: This type of question is better suited for Stack Overflow or a sysadmin forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using an old version where the share/VERSION.txt file was missing from the package.

You should try to install the latest version directly from the git repository because this package evolves rapidly:

```
pip install git+https://git.oceandatalab.com/skim/skimulator.git@master
```

Note that example/params_2017v2_23W.py has been removed from recent versions of the package. It is very likely that this params file is not compatible with the latest version of the skimulator, so please read the documentation before you try to run a simulation with this params file.

Answer (score 0):

To test the software with an example file, the following is required.

Firstly, make sure you have an update version of [`skimulator`](https://git.oceandatalab.com/skim/skimulator), by typing in the `Anaconda` prompt, in the home directory, or wherever you want to place it:

```
git clone https://git.oceandatalab.com/skim/skimulator.git
cd skimulator
python setup.py install
```

making sure you have `git` installed with: `conda install git`

In the `/example` directory create two folders: `\input_fields` & `\skim_output`

```
cd [yourpath]/skimulator/data
```

and unpack orbits data to the `/data` directory via this website:  https://oceandatalab.com/files/skim/orbits.tar.xz

From : https://forum.oceandatalab.com/thread-8.html  download (as a test) 3 `.uss.nc` files (~70 MB each) from:

" Here is an ftp link to WWAVEWATCH III (WW3) wave and currents data
1. for the Gulfstream grid: ftp://ftp.ifremer.fr/ifremer/ww3/HINDCAST/OTHER/SKIM/NATAL_MITGCM_1Y/ "

```
ww3.20111115_uss.nc
ww3.20111116_uss.nc
ww3.20111117_uss.nc
```

Copy them into the `\input_fields` directory. Also, paste the names of the files into a `.txt` file called `list_of_file.txt`. And store the .txt file in `\input_fields`.

Make sure `ww3.20111115_cur.nc` (70 MB) is also copied into `\input_fields`, as indicated in the example file `params_example_6beams.py` or `params_example_8beams.py`.

When running the example file make sure the call to the directory is correct; the default is the home directory. You may need to change this.

From within `\example` directory run the code with e.g.:

```
skimulator params_example_6beams.py
```

It should produce an output in `\skim_output` of .nc files.

You will need [`ncview`](http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html) (Linux or mac) to display the data files, i.e.:

```
ncview WW3_23W_metop_2018_8a_c01_p002.nc
```

To obtain `ncview` for linux/ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install ncview` .

There should be a windows version of `netCDF` (nc) viewer e.g. `ncbrowser` etc. However, I have not got `ncbrowser` working yet. You could also use [`cygwin`](https://www.cygwin.com/) (unix for windows) to install `ncview`. The output GUI data display, looks like this:

[image]

However, this version of the output is not fully functional yet!

---

I was eventually able to get `ncview` to work with `cygwin` (windows 10) and produce the skimulator GUI shown below.

[image]

See:

[An issue with ncview (netCDF visual browser) on cygwin - windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1391975/an-issue-with-ncview-netcdf-visual-browser-on-cygwin-windows-10/1392271#1392271)